# How do I get 'pages' notifications into my own notification inbox?

Tags: facebook, google-plus, facebook-pages, notifications, google-plus-pages

**Both Facebook and Google+** show me notifications in a little menu when someone mentions me or comments on my posts. This is useful.

Both Facebook and in Google+ lets me create pages, and so I've created one for my [company](https://plus.google.com/b/114150208590538284967/114150208590538284967/about) and one for my [product](https://plus.google.com/b/108705856765488140609/108705856765488140609/posts).

**Problem:**
When anyone likes or comments or shares these pages, **the notification is sent to the page and not to my user account.** This means I have to check each page just to see if there are any notifications -- very tedious.

**How can I conveniently monitor notifications about these pages?**
Is there no way to have the notifications delivered to my personal notification menu?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a known problem. There's no setting to have it otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately IFTTT doesn't have a trigger for page notifications or personal messages sent to a page.

There is a setting within the admin options for a facebook page, to trigger an email alert. 
(Edit page > Manage notifications, and selected 'Send notifications to [my email address] when people post to, comment on, or message your Page.') 
But this doesn't seem to be working for me...

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say so but there is absolutely no way you can do that.

One Workaround would be using [ifttt.com](http://ifttt.com) which you can set to send you a SMS/E-mail alert whenever there is a new status, new link or new photo on your page.

Comment: This is useful! Except that neither FB nor G+ are available as [channels](http://ifttt.com/channels) :-/

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun Are you kidding? Facebook is available as a channel.

Comment: @myselpoddar: My bad! The FB icons were removed by my adblocker so I didn't see them listed. Sorry - great help!